# Read File Uploaded Via PostMan or other clients From NodeJS without using Multer

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to read an avatar file uploaded via PostMan or any other client to my ExpressJS API.

So far, the recommendations I have being getting has all being Multer.

I don't want to use Multer as I am having some issues with it. I want to be able to read the file directly and upload it to a remote location of choice

Here is the code I have but not working

```
const getS3Params = (file) => {
  let fileName = file.name;
  let fileType = file.mimetype;
  let fileContent = fs.readFileSync(file); /**Getting an error that says TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received an instance of Object**/
  return {
    Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET_NAME,
    Key: fileName,
    ACL: 'public-read',
    ContentType: fileType,
    Body: fileContent
  };
};
```

Is there a way to read the content of the file without using Multer?

Thanks.

Comment: `readFileSync` is indeed for reading a file by path.

Comment: @MoshFeu Yea, so how can I read a file that was sent in ```req.files``` property without using ```Multer```

Comment: I'm not that expert with this but seems like Multer is indeed popular. I found [`formidable`](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_uploadfiles.asp), maybe you can use it to save the file temporary, send to s3 and delete it after

Comment: Maybe it's better to ask SO members about those issues with multer? Otherwise you need to parse multipart body content by yourself or search another parser like multer

Comment: @mekings Do you solve this problem..!? If you solve please suggest some methods